# How do I convert date mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z format in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

```
var dateType = $filter('date')($scope.datalist[0].OVERRIDE_DATE, "MM/dd/yyyy");
```

I have the output : 05/07/1992

I want to change above date to  `yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z` format ?

Comment: use the Date object toISOString method

Answer (score 2):

`toISOString()` should do what you want.

e.g.

`new Date('05/07/1992').toISOString();`

will give you

`"1992-05-07T07:00:00.000Z"`

Comment: How can I convert "1992-05-07T07:00:00.000Z" back to mm/dd/yyyy format ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Date.prototype.toISOString()` method may be what you want:

```js
const rawDate = $filter('date')($scope.datalist[0].OVERRIDE_DATE, "MM/dd/yyyy");
const formattedDate = new Date(rawDate).toISOString();
```

or, if $scope.datalist[0].OVERRIDE_DATE is already a date object, you could just do:

```js
const formattedDate = $scope.datalist[0].OVERRIDE_DATE.toISOString();
```

[Link to `Date.prototype.toISOString` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)